# Adobe Flex: Accessing Result Event From Main Application In Component MXML

Tags: apache-flex, mxml, xmllist

In my main application I have a result event and an `XMLList`, which is filled with my results. The XMLList is defined outside of a function like so:

```
public var testList:XMLList = new XMLList();
```

But within my result handler it is populated with data from the result and it works fine. I need to create an external component MXML file that will contain a List, but from within that component file I can't access testList from the main application.

I have included `xmlns:local="*"` in each file and my component file also has the following imports:

```
import mx.collections.XMLListCollection;
import mx.controls.Alert;
import mx.core.Application;
import mx.events.FlexEvent;
import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the `testList` as a property of your component.

**Main** - you have the testList from your result event and your custom component.  Pass the `testList` to a property you've defined in the component, such as `data`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
               xmlns:local="*">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            [Bindable]
            public var testList:XMLList = new XMLList();
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <local:CustomComponent data="{testList}" />

</s:Application>
```

**CustomComponent** - from the component you created, access the `testList` from a property, such as `data` in this example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Group xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
         xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
         xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            [Bindable]
            public var data:XMLList;
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:List dataProvider="{new XMLListCollection(data)}" />

</s:Group>
```

Comment: Thankyou for the reply. I tried the following line:
`<local:CustomComponent testData="{testList}" />`
and I got the error: `Could not resolve <local:CustomComponent> to a component implementation `

Comment: Use the component *you* created.  This is just an example.  The core concept here is that putting imports around doesn't help you - you need to pass your `XMLList` to the child component you've created.  Put a XMLList property in your child component, and pass that property from your main app.  Use this example as a guide how to accomplish that.

Comment: I apologise; I've never used the <local> tag so I didn't realise I was supposed to replace CustomComponent with the name of my component. Although i'm now getting new errors, It appears I'm accessing the information, which is all I asked for, so thankyou!

Comment: <local> is the default namespace Flash Builder applies for classes in the same package.  Post a new question if you like and I'll try to help from there.

Comment: Thanks: I've posted my new questions here.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10777471/adobe-flex-cannot-convert-xmllist-to-mx-collections-ilist

Comment: Also I don't suppose you'd mind letting me know how I can also pass on my states to my component? I'm sure I could just do that same as above, but my component won't understand that it's a state though right?

Comment: Yes, same as above set `currentState="{currentState}"` and your Main state is passed to the component state.  Make sure you define the same states in your component as defined in your Main.

Comment: I hope I read this correctly, but I have another error. Here is what my code looks like:
`<local:InfoWindow id="infoWindow" UserData="{userDataListCollection}" currentState="{loggedin}" />`
Error: Access of undefined property loggedin

Comment: If you want the component to be state: "loggedin" than leave out the brackets and just say: `currentState="loggedin"` but if you want its state to always match than say: `currentState="{currentState}"`

Comment: Perhaps i'm doing something very stupid here, but it's just not working. In my parent file I have the declared states 'loggedin' and 'loggedout'. I removed the {} as you suggested so my <local> tag looks like this:
`<local:InfoWindow id="infoWindow" testData="{testListCol}" currentState="loggedin" />`
Then inside the component I copied pasted my state declarations and even set the label inside the component to be `includeIn="loggedin"`
Despite all of this I load my application and immediately (still in loggedout) I see my label. I'm not sure what else I need to do.

Comment: If state is set in the parent, than it is: `<local:InfoWindow id="infoWindow" testData="{testListCol}" currentState="{currentState}" />` which means: set current state of InfoWindow to match the current state of the parent.