# Adobe Flex: Cannot Convert XMLList to mx.collections.IList

Tags: xml, apache-flex

My Flex app runs a service to a php page that pulls data from my database, then structures the result in an XML format. I created a new XMLList called `testList` outside of any functions, then when the results come back (they first come to flex as a single string holding all of the XML code) I have the following code to turn it into XML and then append to my testList:

> var s:String = event.result as String;
>   var xml:XML = new XML(s);
>   testList = xml.user;

The data is used in one function, then it's also passed to a component of mine, where I try to display the XMLList in a List (with testList as dataProvider) and I get the following error:

TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert XMLList@68ffa01 to mx.collections.IList.

I have a feeling it's probably a noob error, but any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

E4X expressions return lists of matching XML. `xml.user` gives you an XMLList of all `user` elements. You can use `XMLListCollection`, which implements `IList`, to wrap the result so you can use it as a dataprovider.

```
var xml:XML = new XML(event.result as String);
var list:IList = new XMLListCollection(xml.user);
```

The other option is to loop though the XMLList and add it to an array or whatever collection you need. If you know for sure that there is only one user, you can do this instead:

```
var user:XML = xml.user[0];
```

Comment: I did what you said and now I have the error:
`TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert mx.collections::XMLListCollection@8396239 to XMLList.`

Comment: Note that you use the XMLList as the source for the XMLListCollection. You should never be putting your XMLListCollection into a variable typed XMLList.

Comment: Thankyou both takteek and Amy. I realised that within my component I was still trying to use XMLList instead of XMLListCollection. It works now.

Comment: @takteek, I have a similar problem would you please have a look at my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14331106/type-coercion-failed-cannot-convert-xmllist106e9af1-to-mx-collections-ilist                           Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You probably are using this inside a module or a swf that you've loaded, and the loader has a different applicationDomain than the parent, and some other loaded module or swf is also using XMLList or XMLListCollection. Without more details on your architecture, I can only tell you to make sure the parent applicationDomain loads in XMLList and/or XMLListCollection before either child, or make sure they both share the parent's applicationDomain.