# Type Coercion failed: cannot convert XMLList@106e9af1 to mx.collections.IList

Tags: web-services, apache-flex, soap-client

using code blew I am trying to parse the following soap response.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
               xmlns:components="components.*"
               xmlns:hellos="services.hellos.*"
               height="957"  creationComplete="initApp()" > 
    <fx:Style source="Styles.css"/>
    <fx:Script>

        <![CDATA[

            import mx.controls.Alert;

            private namespace invesbot = "http://Services.com";
            use namespace invesbot;

            private namespace a = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";
            private namespace b = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"; 
            private namespace c = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
            use namespace a;
            use namespace b;
            use namespace c;

            [Bindable]
            var _result:*



            private function initApp():void
            {
                myService.mycustomers();
            }

        ]]> 
    </fx:Script>
    <fx:Declarations>
        <mx:WebService id="myService" wsdl="http://localhost:8081/WebServiceTest/services/Hellos?wsdl" 
                       showBusyCursor="true" 
                       fault="Alert.show(event.fault.faultString), 'Error'">
            <mx:operation name="mycustomers" resultFormat="e4x">
                <mx:request>
                </mx:request>
            </mx:operation>
        </mx:WebService>

    </fx:Declarations>
<mx:HBox>
        <mx:Text
            text="{myService.mycustomers.lastResult.mycustomersReturn.name}"
            />
    </mx:HBox>
</s:Application>
```

The SOAP response is as following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope
  xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <mycustomersResponse xmlns="http://Services.com">
      <mycustomersReturn>
        <age>28</age>
        <name>John</name>
      </mycustomersReturn>
      <mycustomersReturn>
        <age>29</age>
        <name>Alex</name>
      </mycustomersReturn>
      <mycustomersReturn>
        <age>30</age>
        <name>Jack</name>
      </mycustomersReturn>
    </mycustomersResponse>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Using the above code the output will be

```
<name xmlns="http://Services.com" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">John</name>
<name xmlns="http://Services.com" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">Alex</name>
<name xmlns="http://Services.com" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">Jack</name>
```

but when I use the following code to put the result in dropdown box it gives the following error

```
<s:FormItem label="Employee:"> 
        <s:DropDownList id="dropDownList3"
                        labelField="name"
                        dataProvider ="{myService.mycustomers.lastResult.mycustomersReturn}"/>
    </s:FormItem>
```

TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert XMLList@106e9af1 to mx.collections.IList.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10777471/adobe-flex-cannot-convert-xmllist-to-mx-collections-ilist

Answer (score 1):

You have to wrap your data in an XMLListCollection
The same thing with Arrays, you'll have to wrap them into ArrayCollections.
With the new version of flex sdk 4.9 you can also create VectorLists and VectorCollections.

For example:

```
var iList:IList =  new XMLListCollection(myService.mycustomers.lastResult.mycustomersReturn);
dataProvider = iList;
```

Comment: Some samples would actually be useful here